# Show that $(n + 1)a^n < \frac{b^{n + 1} - a^{n + 1}}{(b-a)} < (n + 1)b^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(b-a)(b^n + b^{n - 1}a + b^{n - 2}a^2 + \ldots + a^n)$

$= (b^{n + 1} - ab^n) + (ab^n - a^2b^{n - 1}) + (a^2b^{n - 1} - a^3b^{n - 2}) + \ldots + (a^nb - a^{n + 1})$

$= b^{n + 1} - a^{n + 1}$, so

$(b^n + b^{n - 1}a + b^{n - 2}a^2 + \ldots + a^n) = \frac{b^{n + 1} - a^{n + 1}}{(b-a)}$

What can I do from here?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ real?

Comment: I assume that $a < b$?

Comment: $0 < a < b \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at $b^n + b^{n - 1}a + b^{n - 2}a^2 + \ldots + a^n$, you have $n+1$ terms. We have
$$
a^n + a^n +\cdots + a^n < b^n + b^{n - 1}a + b^{n - 2}a^2 + \ldots + a^n < b^n + b^n + \cdots + b^n
$$
because $a^n < a^kb^l < b^n$ if $k+l = n$ (and $k, l$ are both positive). Use the definition of multiplication to rewrite $a^n + \cdots +a^n = (n+1)a^n$ and $b^n + \cdots +b^n = (n+1)b^n$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. So many good answers and it's so hard to choose one.

Answer (score 2):

By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there exists $a<c<b$ such that
$$
\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}=(n+1)c^n.
$$
Hence,
$$
(n+1)a^n<\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}<(n+1)b^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

We have that

$$\dfrac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}=b^n+b^{n-1}a+b^{n-2}a^2+\cdots +a^2b^{n-2}+ba^{n-1}+a^n$$

Is not $a^n< b^ia^{n-i}< b^n, \forall i\in \{0,\dots, n\}?$ Are not there $n+1$ summands?